# Combine in App Script Vlookup with IF Statement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Thanks in advance for taking the time to review this thread. I am trying to recreate a formula in App Script that combines Vlookup and multiple IF Statements. Having reviewed just about every post I could find I was able to create the vlookup in app script but the script only works if the lookup value matches the exact value in the other sheet which is not always true. As such I am not sure whether the script should be adjusted to have multiple IF statements similar to the formula it is replacing or whether there is a better option.

Here is an example workbook that has the arrayformula and script.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N2GJR-Otl0Idf2_wTx9XsdFsxj4SDw329uKRM10ivkE/edit?usp=sharing

My main sheet contains a list of product codes(Skus) that are used to look up the product cost in another workbook. Depending on the product, the Product Code(Sku) in the main sheet may contain additional characters which will result in the lookup value not being an exact match with the Product Code in the other workbook. As shown in the picture below, in the products sheet the Product Code (SKU) has 3 variations:

1. Regular - If the product code does NOT start with “S” or contain “@” then it will match the Product Code in the other workbook.
2. Vintage - Some products have the vintage added to Sku.  For example Sku 18 might be entered as Sku 18@2021. In order for the lookup value to work the @2021 needs to be removed.
3. S Product - If the Sku starts with an “S” it means that the product is being split into smaller units. In order to lookup the product cost the leading “S” needs to be removed but the cost value also needs to be divided by the number of units.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(ROW(A1:A)=1,"Cost",
>  
> IF((REGEXMATCH(A1:A,"@")+(LEFT(A1:A,1)="S"))=0,
> VLOOKUP(A1:A,{Imp_Epl!B:B,Imp_Epl!F:F},2,FALSE),
> IF(LEFT(A1:A,1)="S", 
> VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-1),{Imp_Epl!B:B,Imp_Epl!F:F},2,FALSE)/VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-1),{Imp_Epl!B:B,Imp_Epl!D:D},2,FALSE),
> IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A, "@"), 
> VLOOKUP( LEFT(A1:A, SEARCH("@",A1:A) -1) ,{Imp_Epl!B:B,Imp_Epl!F:F},2,FALSE))
> ))))))

Here is the Vlookup script

```
function vlookupalternative() {
const dstwb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();              // Destination workbook
const srcwb = SpreadsheetApp.openById("152Rexxxxxxxxxx");         // Source workbook Id
const dstsheet = dstwb.getSheetByName("COST_SHEET");       // Destination workbook sheet name
const srcsheet = srcwb.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS_SHEET");    // Source workbook sheet name

const srcdata = srcsheet.getRange(2,2,srcsheet.getLastRow()-1,5).getValues()
const searchValues = dstsheet.getRange(2,1,dstsheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues()  

const dstheader = dstsheet.getRange(1,1,1,dstsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].indexOf("PutDatahere")+1; 

const matchSku = searchValues.map(searchRow => {
const matchRow = srcdata.find(r => r[0] == searchRow[0])
return matchRow ? [matchRow[4]] : [null]      // Columns to the right to retrieve value
})

dstsheet.getRange(2,dstheader,dstsheet.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(matchSku)   
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. So, can I ask you about the detail of your question? 1. What is the current issue of your script? 2. About your showing image, where can I see your sample input and output situations? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for helping again @Tanaike. The problem with the script is that it only works if the lookup value is an exact match between both sheets which is not always true. I will try and provide another explanation with the hope that it helps. 


I have two large sheets (in different workbooks);   Sheet 1 is the PRODUCTS_SHEET which contains about 5,000 products. Sheet 2 is the COST_SHEET which contains a list of about 80,000 products and each product's cost. I need the PRODUCTS_SHEET to look up each product's cost from the COST_SHEET.

Comment: The COST_SHEET lists each product's > >  Product Number, Cost and Units. . The PRODUCTS_SHEET lists our current products and their information including the Product Number. The Product Number in the PRODUCTS_SHEET matches the Product Number found in the COST_SHEET but may also contain additional numbers and/or letters.

Comment: `For example: COST_SHEET has Product Number: 18 | Cost $12 | Units 6 `. In the PRODUCTS_SHEET the Product Number may be one of the following:

[[[          `① 18@2023  # includes the year it was made. Lookup value needs “@2023” removed ` ]]]
[[[ `②  S18 “S” means that the product is split up. Remove the “S” to lookup the product and then divide the cost by the Units ($12 / 6 = $2) ` ]]] [[[ `③18  Does not start with “S” and does not contain “@” so nothing needs to be changed in order to lookup value `]]]

If this doesn't help just let me know and I'll mock up a better visual example.

Comment: @Tanaike I added another picture, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your reply, I thought that you wanted to retrieve the values from column "B" of "COST_SHEET", and want to search the retrieved values from column "A" of "PRODUCT_SHEET". Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the detail of `For example: COST_SHEET has Product Number: 18 | Cost $12 | Units 6,,,` in your reply? Unfortunately, I cannot understand it. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike I have added a link to an example workbook that has the formula that was being used as well as the script version that is not working.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your provided Spreadsheet, I cannot still understand `S18 “S” means that the product is split up. Remove the “S” to lookup the product and then divide the cost by the Units ($12 / 6 = $2)`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot understand `The product is sold by the supplier as a pack of 4 cans of beer. which is why you will find 66753 on the Cost Sheet. However, we sell it both as a 4 pack and as invidual cans.`. And also, I cannot understand the logic for obtaining `4`. I apologize for this.

Comment: To make my explanation make sense I will use the information for a product provided in the example workbook. 

Row 15 of the example workbook has Sku S66753, the same Sku is in Row 6 but without the "S". The product is sold by the supplier as a pack of 4 cans of beer using Sku 66753. We sell sell it as a 4 pack using the same Sku 66753 but we also sell the cans individually using Sku S66753. The "S" basically means that we are taking a larger pack size sold by the supplier such as a 4 pack, 6 pack, 12 pack, 15 pack, etc. and selling the product as individual bottles or cans.

Comment: In the Cost Sheet the column "WHOLESALE PRICE-SU" is the Cost the supplier chargers and the "BTL-SU" is how many bottles or cans that are included in that cost. For the Sku 66753 the "BTL-SU" is 4 and the "WHOLESALE PRICE-SU" is $11.02. So our cost for Sku 66753 is $11.02 but for **S**66753 our cost is $2.76 because we are splitting up the 4 pack which costs $11.02 and selling it as 4 individual cans.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the logic for obtaining `4`.

Comment: Thanks for still trying. I’ll try again. It might help if I separate it into parts.

Comment: Part 1: To get my lookup value I need all Skus from the Product List with any “S” removed and any “@####” removed. For example for Sku S66753@2023 the lookup value is 66753.

Comment: Part 2: Matching the lookup value in Part 1 to the Column B (Sku) on the Cost Sheet I need to retrieve two columns of data from the Cost Sheet; Column D (BTL-SU) and Column I (WHOLESALE PRICE-SU) .

Comment: Part 3: IF the Sku started with an “S” my value is Column I divided by Column D if the SKU did not start with an “S” my value is Column I.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Your brilliant, thanks yet again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, from your replying, does the following sample script obtain your expected result?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const productList = ss.getSheetByName("Product List");
  const costSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cost Sheet");
  const range = productList.getRange("A2:A" + productList.getLastRow());
  const costObj = costSheet.getRange("A2:I" + costSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, [, b, , d, , , , , i]) => (o[b] = [d, i], o), {});
  const values = range.getDisplayValues().map(([a]) => {
    const [t1, t2] = a.split("@")[0].split("S");
    return [t2 ? (costObj[t2] ? (costObj[t2][1] / costObj[t2][0]) : null) : (costObj[t1] ? costObj[t1][1] : null)];
  });
  range.offset(0, 11).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used in your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- If you want to reduce the process cost more, how about retrieving the values from "Cost Sheet" with Sheets API as follows? In this case, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.

  ```js
  function sample2() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const productList = ss.getSheetByName("Product List");
    const range = productList.getRange("A2:A" + productList.getLastRow());
    const costObj = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss.getId(), "'Cost Sheet'!A2:I", { valueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE" }).values.reduce((o, [, b, , d, , , , , i]) => (o[b] = [d, i], o), {});
    const values = range.getDisplayValues().map(([a]) => {
      const [t1, t2] = a.split("@")[0].split("S");
      return [t2 ? (costObj[t2] ? (costObj[t2][1] / costObj[t2][0]) : null) : (costObj[t1] ? costObj[t1][1] : null)];
    });
    range.offset(0, 11).setValues(values);
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: YESSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!! Thank you Tanaike. It populated my list of 5,000 products in less than a minute. Unbelievable!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Micah Noble Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too

Comment: one last question, I've tried inserting .setNumberFormat("#,##0.00") in the script in a couple of different spots as some of the values are showing up as text but its not working. I tried both before and after the .setValues arguement but it didn't work. Should I add another line of code to get and set the formating for the entire column?

Comment: @Micah Noble About `one last question,,,`, I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: I will post the additional question in anothe question. In regards to questions as to understanding how your solution works would you prefer that I do that in another post?

Comment: @Micah Noble Thank you for replying. About `I will post the additional question in anothe question.`, I understood it. About `In regards to questions as to understanding how your solution works would you prefer that I do that in another post?`, if you have a question to my answer, please tell me. When the comment can be used, I would like to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the exact match feature from VLOOKUP, in this scenario to avoid using too many arguments, the solution I would like to share is using IFERROR, instead of an IF, IFERROR Returns the first argument if it is not an error value, otherwise returns the second argument if present, or a blank if the second argument is absent.

[image]

The solution is to use REGEXREPLACE

in order to remove the "S" and the "@2023" from the SKU and replace it with a blank, this is the regular_expression:

```
[A-Z](?:)|@[0-9]*
```

Based on the first Google Sheet example you shared, I copied the information on a new Google Sheet using the same exact cell range. Here's the formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4, Sheet1!$B$13:$E$17, 4, FALSE), VLOOKUP(VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A4, "[A-Z](?:)|@[0-9]*", "")), Sheet1!B11:E15, 4, FALSE))
```

Reference:

- [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Comment: Thanks for the help Samuel. I am familiar with the REGEXREPLACE function but did not use it because if the Product Number starts with an "S" the cost needs to be divided by the number of units. Regardless, the vlookup references a sheet with 90,000 rows which is why I need to use app script instead.

Perhaps the best path forward for the script would be to use REGEXREPLACE for the lookup value and then add another function which determines whether the cost value that is retrieved needs to be divided or can remain as it.

Comment: Realized that REGEXREPLACE won't work as the product codes that contain the vintage ie. 98765@2023 need the @2023 removed not just the @

Comment: Thanks for replying, I can see that a solution that helped you achieved what you needed was provided, in regards to your comment about removing **@2023** not just the **@**, the regular_expression I provided in the formula `"[A-Z](?:)|@[0-9]*", ""))` removes the letter **S** and also **@2023**, the regular_expression removes all the numbers that go after the **@** for example: **@2022**, **@2023**.